# Comparing 2D and 3D model in single Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am new to Autodesk Forge Viewer. I want to achieve something like [this](https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator?id=57f3739777c879f48ad54a44) but using splitScreen Extension or in single viewer. Is it possible to do it?   I am using Angular component Forge Viewer 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the splitscreen extension only supports synchronized navigation between the subscenes - that is you can only see different models in the subscenes from the same view/perspective.

Also see this sample [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-navigation.sample) to achieve synchronized view in two separate viewers.

Comment: Can I see Demo of above solution. Demo link is not working right now